# How to join two table in C# web API

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am new at C# entity framework. I am trying to build an API, but stuck in retrieving data from relational table.
I have a ***pei_crops*** table in MS SQL database, where **c_id** is the primary key. I have another table called ***pei_pests***, where **p_id** is the primary key. Another table is ***pei_cropspests*** where I have built relation for which pest attack which crop. Multiple pests can attack one crop and one pest can attack multiple crops. In this ***pei_cropspests*** table I have put **p_id** as primary and foreign key and **c_id** as primary and foreign key as well.

**pei_crops table:**

| c_id | c_name | c_description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Corn | NULL |

**pei_pests table:**

| p_id | p_name | p_URL |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | pest1 | NULL |
| 2 | pest2 | NULL |

**pei_cropspests table:**

| p_id | c_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |

Now In my API I want to show something like that

```json
[
{
    "cId":1,
    "pests":[
             {
               "pId":1,
               "pName": pest1,
               "pURL": null
             },
             {
               "pId":2,
               "pName": pest2,
               "pURL": null
             }

           ]
}
]
```

My get request looks like this so far in C# web API project:

```cs
[Route("Getspecific/{cropId}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSpecific(int cropId)
{
    var cropDetails = await _db.PeiCrops.Where(c=>c.CId == cropId).Include(i=>i.PeiCropspests).ToListAsync();
    return Ok(cropDetails);
}
```

This code returns me only the pID and URL of the pest that effects cID number 1. But I also want the pest name and URL along with their id.

Could someone please show me how to do it. Maybe there is some way to join two table and show the data? I just do not know how to do it in C#. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Entities class:
**PeiCrop:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace PEI_API.EF
{
    public partial class PeiCrop
    {
        public PeiCrop()
        {
            PeiCropimages = new HashSet<PeiCropimage>();
            PeiCropsdiseases = new HashSet<PeiCropsdisease>();
            PeiCropspests = new HashSet<PeiCropspest>();
        }

        public int CId { get; set; }
        public string CName { get; set; }
        public string CPhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public string CDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PeiCropimage> PeiCropimages { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PeiCropsdisease> PeiCropsdiseases { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PeiCropspest> PeiCropspests { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PeiPest:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace PEI_API.EF
{
    public partial class PeiPest
    {
        public PeiPest()
        {
            PeiCropspests = new HashSet<PeiCropspest>();
            PeiPestimages = new HashSet<PeiPestimage>();
        }

        public int PId { get; set; }
        public string PName { get; set; }
        public string PPhotoUrl { get; set; }
        public string PDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<PeiCropspest> PeiCropspests { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PeiPestimage> PeiPestimages { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**PeiCropspest:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

#nullable disable

namespace PEI_API.EF
{
    public partial class PeiCropspest
    {
        public int PId { get; set; }
        public int CId { get; set; }

        public virtual PeiCrop CIdNavigation { get; set; }
        public virtual PeiPest PIdNavigation { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe LINQ can do it?

Comment: @urlreader I am confused and not sure how to integrate this with my current code and return it to API.

Comment: Can you show the entities class?

Comment: @Sami use this site to learn how to ask SQL, is very useful for now and future: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: example is not responding to what you want. Maybe the data is wrong. Both pets has different cid.

Comment: I mean in pei_cropspests, c_id for p_id = 2 should be 1

Comment: @LeandroBardelli thank you for pointing out. I have fixed it

Comment: @vernou I have added the classes to my question. Thank you.

Comment: Can Anyone Help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71743841/how-to-group-columns-by-table-name-in-linq-method-syntax-in-table-relationships, vernou

Comment: #vernou @vernou can you help men with this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71743841/how-to-group-columns-by-table-name-in-linq-method-syntax-in-table-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to configure the relationships :

```cs
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<PeiCropspest>()
            .HasKey(cp => new { cp.PId, cp.CId });

        //Configure one PeiPest to many PeiCropspest
        modelBuilder.Entity<PeiCropspest>()
            // Specify PeiCropspest's navigation property to one PeiPest
            .HasOne(cp => cp.PIdNavigation)
            // Specify PeiPest's navigaton property to many PeiCropspest
            .WithMany(p => p.PeiCropspests)
            // Specify PeiCropspest's navigation property
            // to use this PeiCropspest's property as foreign key
            .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.PId);

        //Configure one PeiCrop to many PeiCropspest
        modelBuilder.Entity<PeiCropspest>()
            // Specify PeiCropspest's navigation shadow property to one PeiCrop
            .HasOne<PeiCrop>()
            // Specify PeiCrop's navigaton property to many PeiCropspest
            .WithMany(c => c.PeiCropspests)
            // Specify PeiCropspest's navigation shadow property
            // to use this PeiCropspest's property as foreign key
            .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.CId);
    }

    public DbSet<PeiCrop> PeiCrops { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do a projection in the LINQ query :

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSpecific(int cropId)
{
    var cropDetails = await _db.PeiCrops
    .Where(c=>c.CId == cropId)
    .Select(c => new {
        cId = c.CId,
        pests = c.PeiCropspests.Select(p => new {
            pId = p.PIdNavigation.PId,
            pName = p.PIdNavigation.PName,
            pUrl = p.PIdNavigation.PPhotoUrl
        })
    })
    .ToListAsync();
    return Ok(cropDetails);
}
```

> Do you know? From EF Core 5, it's possible to do many to many relationship without intermediary entity. This can simplify your entity model. cf. [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many)

Comment: Hey @vernou thank you so much. This one is working for me.

Comment: If this answer answered your question, can you accept it?

Comment: sorry, this is my second post. I did not know the answers can be accepted. Accepted your answer

Answer (score 2):

You're pretty close, but you're also not entirely using EF like you could, I mean you do not actually have to make the relationship table yourself but could refer directly to a list of the entity pei_pests from the entity pei_crop and let EF create the other.

```
//Example just getting one property from each, 
//but you can new a composite return type up if you wish, using select
var cropDetails = await _db.PeiCrops
                            .Where(c=>c.CId == cropId)
                            .Include(i=>i.PeiCropspests)
                            .ThenInclucde(t => t.Pests)
                            .Select(s => new { CropId = s.p_id, PestName = s.PeiCropsPests.Pest.p_name  })
                            .ToListAsync();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-5.0

Comment: I retracted my downvote and upvote you because the example was wrong, not the data.

Comment: `Include` is not needed or used when using a custom `Select` projection.

Comment: Hi @LeandroBardelli I have added the entity classes to my question. I tried to add the codes given by you to my code. I am getting some errors. because some of the tables are not accessible. Like on ThenInclude() t.Pests showing me error that ICollection<PeiCropsPest> does not contain a definition for 'Pests' . Maybe its because I have not shown you the entity classes and you tried to give me an idea. Maybe I need to change some codes

Comment: @Sami oh no, the answer was made for T. Nielsen

Comment: Thanks again. Haha. I mentioned the wrong person.

Comment: @T.nielsen  I have added the entity classes to my question. I tried to add the codes given by you to my code. I am getting some errors. because some of the tables are not accessible. Like on ThenInclude() t.Pests showing me error that ICollection<PeiCropsPest> does not contain a definition for 'Pests' . Maybe its because I have not shown you the entity classes and you tried to give me an idea. Maybe I need to change some codes